# Prove when $G$ is group of transformations of a set $X$, and $a$, $b$ are elements of $X$ then…

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is group of  transformations of a set $X$, and $a$, $b$ are elements of $X$, then

1. $|\{f\in G: (a)f=b\}|$ is equal to $0$ or to $|\{f\in G: (b)f=a\}|$
2. $G_a = \{f\in G: (a)f=a\}$ is a group of transformations

I am little bit confused especially because of statement 1. So I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I think statement (1) should say $|\{f \in G, (a)f=b\}| = |\{f \in G, (b)f=a\}|$, is it possible that you made a mistake? Also, please use MathJax. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117).

Comment: Yes, I made mistake, the (1) statement should be as you have written, it means $ |{f ∈  G, (a)f=b}| $ it is equal to 0  or $ |{f  ∈ G, (b)f=a}| $ But still I do not have any idea how to prove.

Comment: If $f$ maps $a$ onto $b$, then $f^{-1}$ must the inverse, hence map $b$ onto $a$; $f^{-1}$ must be in $G$, since it is a group.

Answer (score 2):

Set $G_{a,b}=\{f\in G: (a)f=b\}$. Then show that the map
$$
\alpha\colon G_{a,b}\to G_{b,a},\qquad (f)\alpha=f^{-1}
$$
is well defined and bijective.

For 2, prove that $G_a=G_{a,a}=\{f\in G:(a)f=a\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.